# Access each index result from enumerate() - Python

Tags: python, enumerate

I have data, that looks like this:

```
Name Nm1    *    *
Ind1     AACTCAGCTCACG
Ind2     GTCATCGCTACGA 
Ind3     CTTCAAACTGACT
```

I need to grab the letter from each position marked by an asterix in the "Name"-line and print this, along with the index of the asterix

So the result would be

```
Ind1, 12, T
Ind2, 12, A
Ind3, 12, C
Ind1, 17, T
Ind2, 17, T
Ind3, 17, T
```

I'm trying to use `enumerate()` to retrieve the positions of the asterix's, and then my thought was, that I could use these indexes to grab the letters.

```
import sys
import csv

input = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
Output = open(sys.argv[1]+"_processed", 'w')

indlist = (["Individual_1,", "Individual_2,", "Individual_3,"])

with (input) as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if '*' in line:
            LocusID = line[2:13]
            LocusIDstr = LocusID.strip()
            hit = line
            for i, x in enumerate(hit):
                     if x=='*':
                      position = i
                      print position

    for item in indlist:
        Output.write("%s%s%s\n" % (item, LocusIDstr, position))

Output.close()
```

If the `enumerate()`outputs e.g.

```
12
17
```

How do I access each index seperately?

Also, when I print the position, I get the numbers I want. When I write to the file, however, only the last position is written. Why is this?

----------------EDIT-----------------

After advice below, I have edited split up my code to make it a bit more simple (for me) to understand.

```
import sys
import csv

input = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
Output = open(sys.argv[1]+"_FGT_Data", 'w')

indlist = (["Individual_1,", "Individual_2,", "Individual_3,"])

with (input) as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if '*' in line:
            LocusID = line[2:13]
            LocusIDstr = LocusID.strip()
            print LocusIDstr
            hit = line
            for i, x in enumerate(hit):
                    if x=='*':
                      position = i
                      #print position

input = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')

with (input) as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        if line [0] == ">":
            print line[position], position

with (Output) as writefile:
    for item in indlist:
        writefile.write("%s%s%s\n" % (item, LocusIDstr, position))

Output.close()
```

I still do not have a solution for how to acces each of the indexes, though.

Comment: As for the latter: The `for`-loop where you are writing the index position is outside of the loop where you iterate over the lines in the file. Hence it is only executed once.

Comment: you can use `list(line)` to convert the string into a character array, then `zip()` the three resulting arrays up, then `extend()` the zipped arrays which have an `*` as thier first element, finally filter the array to not include the `*`.

Comment: Thank you, @dhke, I see that.
However, when I move the chunk of code to the right, I do get item and LocusIDstr written several times, but again it is only the last index position that is written.

Comment: If your first go at it, returns the indices then open the file again and, this time, grab the characters at those positions for each line. You do not need  to get the job done in one pass. A lot of the times, when performing IO, an initial pass over the data is wise.

Comment: Thank you, @Mr. Polywhirl. A simple thing like doing the job in several goes may seem trivial, but it has already helped me a lot, so thank you for that advice.
How would your suggestion of using `list(line)` work? I have tried to use it as `list(position)` , position being the output from enumerate, but I get the error "'int' object is not iterable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**
changed to work with the file you gave me in your comment. if you have made this file yourself, consider working with columns next time.

```
import sys

read_file = sys.argv[1]
write_file = "%s_processed.%s"%(sys.argv[1].split('.')[0],sys.argv[1].split('.')[1])
indexes = []
lines_to_write = []

with open(read_file,'r') as getindex:
    first_line = getindex.readline()
    for i, x in enumerate(first_line):
        if x == '*':
            indexes.append(i-11)

with open(read_file,'r') as getsnps:
    for line in getsnps:
        if line.startswith(">"):
            sequence = line.split("    ")[1]
            for z in indexes:
                string_to_append = "%s\t%s\t%s"%(line.split("    ")[0],z+1,sequence[z])
                lines_to_write.append(string_to_append)

with open(write_file,"w") as write_file:
    write_file.write("\n".join(lines_to_write))
```

Comment: Thank you, @zazga. I have been looking at biopython, but I have not taken the leap yet. I am a complete newbie to programming, so the learning curve is steep. What I need in the above problem, is to grab the SNP's for each position marked by an asterix. Do you know is biopython can do something like that straight from the box?

Comment: It could be done with biopython, but since you were pretty close already I figured I might aswell see if I can come up with a solution. you have to be carefull with the way you open your files, since you never closed your input file.

Comment: When I try your suggestion, @zazga, I get the error `first_line = getindex.readline().split("\t")[2]
IndexError: list index out of range`.


If I convert the output from enumerate to a string with `str(position)` and split the lines of the string with `str.splitlines()`, would I then be able to access each of the indexes separately?

Comment: @Hjalte This means that your file is not tab delimited. How did you get this file? splitting on enumerate will not work because you have a file indented with spaces. How did you get this file? and is it possible to give me a copy via dropbox,drive,tinyupload? is it possible to convert the file to tab delimited file?

Comment: The file is an output from a sequencing analysis. 
You can see first part of the data here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3j4i04s2rg6b63h/AADkWG3OcsutTiSsyTl8L2Vda?dl=0
The data continues with 1000's of loci similar to the one you see.
By using enumerate, I do get the numbers I want (that correspond to the position of each of the asterix's). 31, 119, 140 for the uploaded file. If I convert them to str, they are written as ['31'], ['119'], ['140']. If I use `splitlines`, I get the numbers as a matrix. Shouldn't it be possible to access each of the indexes from here?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure, if the file can be converted to tab delimited, since the asterix's are seperated by spaces, and I need the exact position of these to retrieve the snp's.